# How can I split a string based on the title of the words?

Tags: python, built-in

For example I have followed string:

```
names = "JohnDoeEmmyGooseRichardNickson"
```

How can I split that string based on the title of the words?
So every time a capital letter occurs, the string will be split up.

Is there a way to do this with the `split()` method? (no regex)

That I will get:

```
namesL = ["John","Doe","Emmy","Goose","Richard","Nickson"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `regex`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "TheLongAndWindingRoad ABC A123B45"
>>> re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", s).split()
# output
['The', 'Long', 'And', 'Winding', 'Road', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A123', 'B45']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't do it with the split method, but doable with re:

```
import re
namesL = re.split("(?=[A-Z])", names)[1:]
```

Keep in mind the first entry will be an empty string (as the first word is also capitalized) so we're removing it.

Comment: `re.split(r'(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])',names)` will eliminate the empty string

Comment: @MarkTolonen prefer keeping the RE simpler and just stripping it.